# I tried a make a calculator but it gives an error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic calculator, but when I try to start it it gives a `string is not int` error, what's the problem? Here is my current code:

```
def Add(number1, number2):
    return number1+number2
    
def Minus (number1, number2):
    return number1-number2
    
def Multiply (number1, number2):
    return number1*number2
    
def Divide (number1, number2):
    return number1/number2
    
print("Operation?")
print("1: Add")
print("2: Minus")
print("3: Multiply")
print("4: Divide")

operation= int(input("Please selecet an operation..."))
number1= int(input("Enter Number1"))
number2= int(input("Enter Number2"))

if operation==1:
    print("Answer= "+ int(number1+number2))
elif operation==2:
    print("Answer= "+ int(number1-number2))
elif operation==3:
    print("Answer= "+ int(number1*number2))
elif operatipn==4:
    print("Answer= "+ int(number1/number2))
else:
    print("You didn't choose anything in list")
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>

Comment: @MuhammetAYDIN The error tells you everything you need to know. You can't concatenate string with integers. You might also want to take a look at the *operator* module and save yourself some coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to add an int object to a str object in the print statements:

```
print("Answer= "+ int(number1-number2))
```

you just need to convert it to str not an int because the result of the - or + operations on int objects will be int:

```
print("Answer= "+ str(number1-number2))
```

Comment: f-string would be far superior. *print(f'Answer={number1-number2}')*

Answer (score 0):

Try using **,** instead of **+** :

```
def Add(number1, number2):
    return number1+number2
    
def Minus (number1, number2):
    return number1-number2
    
def Multiply (number1, number2):
    return number1*number2
    
def Divide (number1, number2):
    return number1/number2
    
print("Operation?")
print("1: Add")
print("2: Minus")
print("3: Multiply")
print("4: Divide")

operation= int(input("Please selecet an operation..."))
number1= int(input("Enter Number1"))
number2= int(input("Enter Number2"))

if operation==1:
    print("Answer= ", int(number1+number2))
elif operation==2:
    print("Answer= ", int(number1-number2))
elif operation==3:
    print("Answer= ", int(number1*number2))
elif operatipn==4:
    print("Answer= ", int(number1/number2))
else:
    print("You didn't choose anything in list")
```

Answer (score 0):

With print you should type a coma "," instead of "+"

`print("Answer= ", int(number1+number2))`

Try it and see, if it doesn't work then try removing int() from your prints!

```
 print("Answer= ", number1+number2)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can solve the above question in below following way as well without `if condition`

Dictionary is most **powerful** in this case when you don't want to write `'N'` number of times the `if statements`

**First way :**

```
def Add(number1, number2):
    return number1+number2
    
def Minus (number1, number2):
    return number1-number2
    
def Multiply (number1, number2):
    return number1*number2
    
def Divide (number1, number2):
    return number1/number2

number1 = int(input('Enter number 1 : '))
number2 = int(input('Enter number 2 : '))

myuserinput = int(input('Enter the option : '))

myoption = { 1 : Add(number1, number2) , 2 : Minus(number1, number2) , 3 : Multiply(number1, number2) , 4:Divide (number1, number2) } 


myoption.get(myuserinput,'Please provide proper input')
```

**Second way :**

```
def Add(number1, number2):
    result = number1 + number2 
    return 'Answer : {0}'.format(result)
    
def Minus (number1, number2):
    result = number1 - number2 
    return 'Answer : {0}'.format(result)
    
def Multiply (number1, number2):
    result = number1 * number2 
    return 'Answer : {0}'.format(result)
    
def Divide (number1, number2):
    result = number1 / number2 
    return 'Answer : {0}'.format(result)

number1 = int(input('Enter number 1 : '))
number2 = int(input('Enter number 2 : '))

myuserinput = int(input('Enter the option : '))

myoption = { 1 : Add(number1, number2) , 2 : Minus(number1, number2) , 3 : Multiply(number1, number2) , 4:Divide (number1, number2) } 


myoption.get(myuserinput,'Please provide proper input')
```

Comment: You'r so professional, thanks